# How to cache bust ES6 javascript modules with nginx and 302 redirection

Tags: javascript, nginx, browser-cache

I'm hosting an ES6 javascript module using nginx. Modern browsers automatically load its [imported dependencies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). Since they are static I want browsers to cache them. But I also want end users to automatically retrieve updates of my module, once a I deploy a new version (Cache Busting).

Assume the following files and dependencies:

```
/a.js ---> b.js
/b.js
```

During build I change their filenames such that they contain their md5 hash:

```
/a.be8654ac0f52d085d1d91a8f447329e2.md5.js ---> b.js
/b.14a723a49c59b609d5b2614204bd5513.md5.js
```

I want all requests for a.js and b.js to be redirected to their respective hash filenames.

```
/a.js ---> /a.be8654ac0f52d085d1d91a8f447329e2.md5.js
/b.js ---> /b.14a723a49c59b609d5b2614204bd5513.md5.js
```

I want nginx to take care of identifying hashed filenames and delivering them with cache control headers. This should be possible like so:

```
# Cachable Javascript
location ~* \.[\d\w]{32}\.md5.js$ {
  expires 1y;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

All other (non-hashed) JS resources should be redirected to their respective hash filename version. If I release a new version of a.js and b.js (with new md5 hashes) I want the nginx configuration to work without adjustments.

How can I configure nginx accordingly? Is this possible at all with nginx? If not, I am open for other approaches.